# Changing an Object / class

Tags: android, class, android-arrayadapter

I am working on an Android app and I seem to be stuck with a simple progamming problem:

I have the following class for an ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyClass {
private String ID;
private String text;


public MyClass(String ID, String text) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.text = text; 
}


public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}


public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}}
```

I create new MyClass-Objects in another activity. This works. Now I want to change a specific Object at a certain position. How can I do this? I tried

```
MyClass myclass.get(position).setText("new text");
```

But this doesnt seem to work. It says: Cannot resolve method get().

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are creating object of MyClass

Comment: for(int i=0; i < Text.size(); i++) 
                {
                   
                   MyClass myclass = new MyClass(ID.get(i), Text.get(i));
           
                    Adapter.add(myclass);

                }

Comment: Than instead of 'myclass.get(position).setText("new text");' you should try 'Adapter.get(position).setText("new text");'

Comment: Ok, i will try it. I knew it was a simple solution. Thank you ;)

Comment: Your welcome. Let me know